# Content around Responsive image in fixed Position

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I have got this diagram and some values around it; this is working fine as long as the image is not responsive. However when I include the responsiveness class, the values tend to get distorted on different screens.

Here is the JS code for dynamically positioning of the values around the code.

```
var letter , letter1 , letter2 , letter3;

var letter = {
  label: a,
  top: 253,
  left: 29
}

var letter1 = {
  label: b,
  top: 160,
  left: 150
}

var letter2 = {
  label: c,
  top: 70,
  left: 350
}

var letter3 = {
  label: d,
  top: 270,
  left: 260
}

var letter_elem = document.createElement('span');
letter_elem.style.top = letter.top + 'px';
letter_elem.style.left = letter.left + 'px';
letter_elem.innerHTML = letter.label;
letter_elem.className = 'sam_number';

var letter_elem1 = document.createElement('span');
letter_elem1.style.top = letter1.top + 'px';
letter_elem1.style.left = letter1.left + 'px';
letter_elem1.innerHTML = letter1.label;
letter_elem1.className = 'sam_number';

var letter_elem2 = document.createElement('span');
letter_elem2.style.top = letter2.top + 'px';
letter_elem2.style.left = letter2.left + 'px';
letter_elem2.innerHTML = letter2.label;
letter_elem2.className = 'sam_number';

var letter_elem3 = document.createElement('span');
letter_elem3.style.top = letter3.top + 'px';
letter_elem3.style.left = letter3.left + 'px';
letter_elem3.innerHTML = letter3.label;
letter_elem3.className = 'sam_number';
```

I am quite sure it has something to do with the top and left position.

**Here is the links:**

Non Responsive Image; the values are positioned perfectly but image gets cut on some mobile devices.

http://ssdmm.org/if/simple/562.html

Responsive Image Code:

http://ssdmm.org/if/responsive/562.html

Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Can you add your html and css? Maybe jsfiddle? I can tell you this working with percentages is the best results I have gotten opposed to px. Scales perfectly when framed properly..

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I have added the link to the responsive image code as well. Yes I know percentage would be better than px, however I am not well versed with using % in designing.

Comment: No luck with % too, the position of the number changes in that case as well. though not so significantly.

Answer (score 0):

About to redit it for you on percentage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; however the values have stopped appearing onSelection of the values in your JSFiddle Demo. 

Here is the link to the responsive image code.. http://ssdmm.org/if/responsive/562.html

Comment: I did not load all the codes or resources, the focus is just on the div areas and the image. Try and replace this in a test environment loading all your code and resources.. see update that I will now add.